# $ _SERVER ['REMOTE_ADDR'] return IP of server, not visitor IP

Tags: php

My php script `$_SERVER ['REMOTE_ADDR']` return allday IP of my server does not the visitor IP

```
$temps_session =15;
$temps_actuel= date("U");
$user_ip=$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
$req_ip_exist = $bdd->prepare('SELECT * FROM `online` WHERE  `user_ip`=?');
 $req_ip_exist ->execute(array($user_ip));
 $ip_exist=$req_ip_exist->rowCount();
 if ($ip_exist==0) {
  $add_ip =$bdd->prepare('INSERT INTO `online` (`user_ip`,`time`) VALUES (?,?)');
  $add_ip->execute(array($user_ip,$temps_actuel));

 }else{
  $update_ip= $bdd->prepare('UPDATE `online` SET `time`=? WHERE 
 `user_ip`=?');
  $update_ip->execute(array($temps_actuel,$user_ip));
 }
 $session_delete_time=$temps_actuel-$temps_session;
 $del_ip=$bdd->prepare('DELETE FROM online WHERE `time`<?');
 $del_ip->execute(array($session_delete_time));
 $show_user_nbr= $bdd->query('SELECT * FROM online');
 $user_nbr =  $show_use
 r_nbr->rowCount();
```

Comment: Please paste your code here, not image.Please check [how to ask a good question on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: In question, not in comments.

Comment: Please update your first post. You can use the `code` balise to show your code in a good way

Comment: I am unable to understand your title `"my php script $ _SERVER ['REMOTE_ADDR'] return allday l IP of my server does not pa the visitor IP"`.Please clarify

Comment: Is my correction of your grammar correct? `$_SERVER ['REMOTE_ADDR']` is returning the server's IP, not the clients?

Comment: I need IP Clients for count Total visits online

Answer (score -1, accepted):

you may use this function

```
function getRealIpAddr()
{
    if (!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP']))   //check ip from share internet
    {
      $ip=$_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'];
    }
    elseif (!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR']))   //to check ip is pass from proxy
    {
      $ip=$_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'];
    }
    else
    {
      $ip=$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
    }
    return $ip;
}

$ipaddr = getRealIpAddr();
```

Comment: No, don't do that. The `Http-Client-Ip` and `X-Forwarded-For` headers may be sent by the client, and can contain anything at all. (Possibly not even an IP address.)

Comment: @duskwuff If OP is behind a proxy of their own control (Cloudflare, HAProxy, etc.) they *may* be able to trust `X-Forwarded-For`. Best to only trust it when `$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']` matches the internal IP of the proxy, though.

Comment: @ceejayoz Right. My point is, don't just blindly go trusting random HTTP headers because you saw some code on Stack Overflow.

Comment: STOP - Minus voting when it works????????????????????????? $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] gave me my server ip the answer was correct, some retired put -minus vote to confuse the new readers.